# amdgpu breaks when iGPU multimonitor is enabled, integrated not usable at all

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics

Intel i7-4770, AMD RX 480 GPU. This is a desktop machine, no hybrid here. The primary display is connected directly to the Radeon via DP. Secondary display is connected to the motherboard over DVI-D.

This is a pretty fresh install of Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04.1. I had to install newer Mesa from a PPA (ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa) just to get the discrete GPU running at all, but when it's the only display device present, everything seems to be working. Here's how that Xorg.log looks: http://pastebin.com/u3nVHhD7

Problem is, I want to use the integrated GPU for a second display, to keep the load off the primary. But when I enable iGPU multimonitor in the BIOS, things immediately break, badly. Hardware rendering goes out the window completely, and X sees the integrated card, but none of its outputs appear in xrandr. Here's what Xorg.log looks like now: http://pastebin.com/BaQ7icJ0

They both show up in lspci:

> 00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 67df (rev c7)

And the same setup is working under Win7.

Comment: You may have had that setup in Windows but the Linux driver doesn't allow for simultaneous use.

Comment: Then, how does hybrid graphics support work? Or is this a limitation a result of implementing support for hybrid graphics?